# pdfmake: Table headers not coming appearing for a few tables

Tags: node.js, server-side, pdfmake

I am trying to create dynamic table content and it seems to be working fine. the content is of following type

```
    content: [
          {
            text: "5.24011.01.0",
            style: "header",
            pageBreak: "before",
          },
          {
            table: {
              widths: [
                "*",
                "*",
                "*",
                "*",
                "*",
              ],
              headerRows: 1,
              body: [
                [
                  {
                    text: "Assembly",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Description",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Reason For Variance",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Component",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Scrap Quantity",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                ],
                [
                  "5.24011.01.0",
                  "Damage",
                  "O600",
                  "7.08982.00.0",
                  3,
                ],
              ],
              margin: [
                5,
                2,
                10,
                20,
              ],
              height: "50px",
            },
          },
          {
            text: "7.09062.05.0",
            style: "header",
            pageBreak: "before",
          },
          {
            table: {
              widths: [
                "*",
                "*",
                "*",
                "*",
                "*",
              ],
              headerRows: 1,
              body: [
                [
                  {
                    text: "Assembly",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Description",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Reason For Variance",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Component",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Scrap Quantity",
                    style: "tableHeader",
                  },
                ],
                [
                  "7.09062.05.0",
                  "Destructive quality test",
                  "7000",
                  "3.69438.00.0",
                  1,
                ],
              ],
              margin: [
                5,
                2,
                10,
                20,
              ],
              height: "50px",
            },
          },

        ],
```

the challenge is while the first table has header and is working fine, however the second one does not :!.

to my utter disappointment when I try the same code in pdfmake playground, all seems be to working fine!

any suggestions would be appreciated as I have tried numerous options but nothing seems to be working !

bTW i am using serverside code

```
let pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
```

where `docDefinition` is the `json` mentioned above

I have attached screenshot of the problematic table

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that , once you have used a variable pdf make variable are not fully reuseable , so if you are using a variable for pushing same  headers to multiple table in for loop then you have to push headers as in picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqzyT.jpg)