Headers not showing in second table with PDFMake
I am using PDFMake to generate two tables side by side in a PDF. The first table renders correctly and shows the text in its header row, but the second table in the right column shows the header row but does not place the header text in the header row cells. I would like the header row to be displayed at the top of both tables. I am using the latest stable release of PDFMake. Any insight on what the issue is?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- PDF Make v0.2.10 -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.10/pdfmake.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.10/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="writeTables()">Make tables</button>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
  function writeTables() {
    const tableHeaders = [
        { text: 'Last Name', style: 'tableHeader' },
        { text: 'First Name', style: 'tableHeader' },
        { text: 'Grade', style: 'tableHeader' },
        { text: 'Class', style: 'tableHeader' }
    ];

    const leftTableBody = [
        tableHeaders,
        ['Doe', 'John', '5', 'A']
    ];

    const rightTableBody = [
        tableHeaders,
        ['Smith', 'Jane', '6', 'B']
    ];

    const columns = [
        {
            width: '50%',
            table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                widths: ['*', '*', 40, 40],
                body: leftTableBody
            }
        },
        {
            width: '50%',
            table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                widths: ['*', '*', 40, 40],
                body: rightTableBody
            }
        }
    ];

    const docDefinition = {
        pageSize: 'LETTER',
        pageOrientation: 'portrait',
        pageMargins: [40, 40, 40, 40], // Standard margins
        content: [
            { columns: columns, columnGap: 10 }
        ],
        styles: {
            tableHeader: { fontSize: 12, bold: true, fillColor: 'gray' },
            tableCell: { fontSize: 12 }
        }
    };

    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('TableTest.pdf');
  }
</script>


Thanks, this seems to be the fix. The variables need to be unique to each header row. I changed the constructions to add L/R as per your suggestion so they are unique and the output is correct.

It appears from others experience see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630526/10802527
That in a live setting PDFKit consumes variables on usage , thus cannot be used twice. Therefore in Live demo setting, the headers as 2 different constants work.
I suggest replace
    const tableHeaders = [
        { text: 'Last Name', style: 'tableHeader' },
        {...
 ...
    const leftTableBody = [
        tableHeaders,
        ['Doe', 'John', '5', 'A']
    ];
    const rightTableBody = [
        tableHeaders,
        ['Smith', 'Jane', '6', 'B']
    ];
...

with
    const tableHeaderL = [
        { text: 'Last Name', style: 'tableHeader' },
        {...
 ...
    const tableHeaderR = [
        { text: 'Last Name', style: 'tableHeader' },
        {...
 ...
    const leftTableBody = [
        tableHeaderL,
        ['Doe', 'John', '5', 'A']
    ];
    const rightTableBody = [
        tableHeaderR,
        ['Smith', 'Jane', '6', 'B']
    ];
...

